# How am I able to extract only time in this simple example in python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

`from datetime import datetime
dt=datetime.strptime('01:45:56PM', '%I:%M:%S%p')
print(dt)`

```
Output:1900-01-01 13:45:56
```

where I just want 13:45:56 as my answer.
How do I extract the time only from the answer.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Can't you simply drop the string's last two characters?

Comment: If you don't want the date, use a time instead of a datetime.

Answer (score 4):

Use time function from your datetime object :

```
from datetime import datetime
dt=datetime.strptime('01:45:56PM', '%I:%M:%S%p')
print(dt.time())
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `strftime` on date object to format the date object in desired forma, which is `%H:%M:%S`:

> %H - Hours in 24-Hour Format.
>
> %M - minutes
>
> %S - seconds

```
from datetime import datetime
dt=datetime.strptime('01:45:56PM', '%H:%M:%S%p')
print dt.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
>>> 13:45:56
```

Comment: Edited @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: Thanks a lot...It helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

just convert the date into string and get the time part from it.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt=datetime.strptime('01:45:56PM', '%I:%M:%S%p')
print(str(dt).split(' ')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using python time module

```
import time
time_tuple = time.strptime("01:45:56", "%I:%M:%S%p")
output = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time_tuple)
```

For more reference you can visit https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html